# WhatsApp vanished from phone, what has happened?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Works well and handy to have BUT..... I don't know what has happened, I used WhatsApp late evening on 30 June 2020. I don't turn off the phone over night.
When I awoke the following morning (1 July) WhatsApp had vanished from the home screen on my Android Blackview BV5500pro. Not only that but it had also vanished from my apps!
I've asked someone if I'm still in their WA contacts and I am but they haven't sent me a message as requested to see what, if anything, happens.
Just to clarify, the icon has not been moved to any folder on the home screen and it does not appear in my installed apps.
What am I to do?

Comment: Without further troubleshooting, it's quite difficult to answer "what has happened", but if it doesn't appear in the installed apps, have you tried downloading/reinstalling it?

Comment: Was the installed WhatsApp version the original version from Google Play Store?

Comment: Have you tried installing it?

Comment: It was the original version. I thought it might be "hidden" somewhere. I've done as much searching as I know how to. If I reinstall WA, am I right in saying all my messages will no longer be visible and contacts will have to be loaded again?

Comment: try pm enable/ install-existing from adb. there exist LegacyWhatsApp v2.11.431 you can install from adb without data loss (if any data still exist) https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/tool-whatsapp-key-db-extractor-crypt6-12-non-root-updated-october-2016.2770982/post-81902381

Comment: But first, try [mtk-su](https://www.xda-developers.com/mediatek-su-rootkit-exploit) if it works you can copy */data/data/com.whatsapp* directly (if exist). it's very easy to execute mtk-su and it does not root or harm your device, it just gives you temporary root shell on adb

Comment: WhatsApp vanished from your phone.  What has happened?  ***Your life has just dramatically improved.***

Comment: Hello everyone who has offered advice. I tried the procedures suggested but got lost along the way. I did a reinstall from Play Store and got a total reinstall with all previous messages and contacts. Looks like I had backed up all previous activity so it was installed as before. Fortunately I don't live for social media and still prefer to talk directly.